# Trying to send UDP packets through a Lewei 5G Wi-Fi modules using the onboard RX pin using Arduino serial

Tags: arduino, udp, wifi

I have a 5G Wi-Fi module hooked up to an [Arduino Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official) 33 [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) via the RX/TX pins. I can send [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) packets from a UDP monitor application on Android using port 50000 over UDP and receive them on the Wi-Fi modules TX pin that is connected to Arduino's RX pin and print it on the serial monitor using a baud rate of [115,200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings), but I can't send any packets or anything for that matter on the modules RX pin.

At this point I’m just trying to send anything that can be received by another device that is connected on the same Wi-Fi network. The Wi-Fi module I’m using I can’t seem to find any information on as the Wi-Fi module was taken out of a cheap Chinese drone.

This is the exact same model first link below....

Notice the four wires... Two are for the power, and the other two wires are TX and RX. I believe they are used as serial as I can receive from the modules TX that’s connected directly to the Arduino's RX serial when I send a UDP message on port 5000 to IP address 192.168.0.1 from a (UDP application on Android). So there must be a way to send data back to the Android application by using the modules RX wire, just like the flight controller did that was previously connected.

*[Wltoys XK X1 RC Quadcopter Spare Parts 5G WIFI 1080P Camera Module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000228028568.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2nld)*

appears to be made by this company:

[Shenzhen Lewei Innovation Technology](http://www.le-wei.com/eacp_view.asp?id=59) (LW1801)

I’m sure I have to send a UDP packet (header plus data) to the device I want to send the UDP message to, i.e., the UDP monitor application I’m using on Android. I know there are UDP libraries available, but they all seem to use Wi-Fi modules that aren't connected via serial RX/TX.

Do I need to construct a UDP packet containing the port and IP address of the device I want to receive the message to? If so, how would I do this using Arduino, but only sending the information on the Arduino serial TX line? Also I am not sure if the constructed packet should be in binary or hexadecimal.

Something like...

```
// Example only - UDP in binary
String COMPLETE_UDP_DATAGRAM_PACKET="110000110101000011000011010100000000000000000100101101001101000001001000011011110110110001100001";

// Example only - UDP in hexadecimal
String COMPLETE_UDP_DATAGRAM_PACKET="C350C3500004B4D0486F6C61";

serial.write(COMPLETE_UDP_DATAGRAM_PACKET);

// Hhhm or something like this maybe. Could this possibly work?
// No, maybe not as I think the UDP var needs to be bound first.
serial.write(udp.beginPacket(IP,port));
serial.write(udp.send(packet));
serial.write(udp.endPacket());
```

UPDATE: The Wi-Fi module I’m using was connected to a toy drone. The TX/RX pins were being used for telemetry back and fourth from the drone application to the Wi-Fi module, then the drones flight controller. The flight controller was originally sending information on the same Wi-Fi RX pin in the form of UDP that I’m trying to accomplish now, but because I don't have the flight controller anymore, I can’t hook it back up to sniff the packets that the (flight controller) was sending to the Wi-Fi device's RX pins. If so, I could maybe sniff the packets using [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) and figure out what to send on the .write() or .print() function to the module RX pin that will then be sent to the receiving device, i.e., IP address 192.168.0.20, port 50000.

The Arduino code is below:

```
UART WIfISerial(digitalPinToPinName(A3), digitalPinToPinName(A2), NC, NC);

// If anything comes in from the Wi-Fi module
// TX pin that is connected to the Arduino RX.

if (WIfISerial.available()) {
    //// This works perfect, any upd application can send UDP messages here

    Serial.println(WIfISerial.read()); // Read it and send it out to Serial
}


if (Serial.available()) { // If anything comes in on Serial then send to the Wi-Fi module
    // UDP packet
    //WIfISerial.print("0100010100000000000000000011001110000011001111100000000000000000100000000001000100110110000101011100000010101000000000000000000111000000101010000000000000010100100111000100000011000011010100000000000000011111011000010011101100110001001100000011101000110010001101000011101000110001001110000010000001110000011011010010000000110010001100000011001000110011001110010011010100110001001101100011000000111000001110010000");

    // Send some data back to the UDP monitor Android application
    WIfISerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

UPDATE: after getting my hands back on the flight controller, I connected the Wi-Fi unit back up to the flight controller and read the packets coming in to the Wi-Fi module. I have successfully sent a packet of data using the following code.

```
// Yes, this works, but why?? I don’t think this is UDP
WIfISerial.write(0xFF); // Beginning of packet
WIfISerial.write(0xFE); // Beginning of packet
WIfISerial.write(0x06); // Packet size in bytes
WIfISerial.write(0x09);
WIfISerial.write(0x06);
WIfISerial.write(0x04);
WIfISerial.write(0xFF);
WIfISerial.write(0xFF);
WIfISerial.write(0xFF);
```

Comment: What exactly is `WIfISerial`? an UDP instance? What UDP library you are using? I doubt you can send a udp packet with `WIfISerial.write()` as a UDP packet usually need to specify an IP and port before sending, so it is general has the idiom of `udp.beginPacket(IP,port); udp.send(packet); udp.endPacket();`.

Comment: My apologies, WIfISerial is just my declared instance of a software serial port ive put on specific pins using arduino nano 33 ble, ive updated the code to show. Im not using any libraries as I can receive data with no issues just need to possibly build a hardcoded datagram packet that needs to send on the serial tx to the wifi module rx pin because it can receive data on the arduino rx pin from the wifi modules rx pin.

Comment: I just noticed that the datagram `C350C3500004B4D0486F6C61` that you are trying to send is not a valid datagram, it shows that you are sending from source port number 50000 (`C350`) to the destination  port of 5000(`C350`)?, are you sure the udp server using port 50000?  and you had an invalid length `0004`, the length of a datagram is the length of the header + length of the payload , and your payload after checksum is 4-byte as ASCII "hola", so the length of the data is 8+4=12 or `000C`.

Comment: I have  kinda figured it out now  as I have sent and received a packet successfully. Thanks for your input/help  (Hcheung)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have it working. It is quite simple, really :(

The module is not sending UDP packets as I initially thought. Only UDP packets are sent to the module when connected on the same network. The wifi module itsel actually sends data as fffe=header 0x04=size of following data in bytes 0x06, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04=data in bytes

```
byte message[] = {0xFF, 0xFE, dataBytes+2, s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], 0x06, 0x05};

WIfISerial.write(message, sizeof(message));
```